# Facebook Application authorization for cron job

Tags: php, facebook, post, cron, authorization

I have an facebook application which sends links to fan page walls. Everything is working when i call the .php file from my browser but when i call the same page from cronjob it can't run the facebook application because of the authorization problem. I don't want to enter my username/password to the php file. Is there a setting to authorize the cronjob and post to page walls?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can authorize any facebook application using cronjobs, you have to authorize manually and then create a cron job with your wall posting link!

Comment: If you've coded your app properly, then go to your app and it has to redirect you to the authorization page which will basically ask you to give some permissions to your app, once you allow the app, you've successfully authorized your app!

Have a look at these tutorial for more details: [fb authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)
and 
[php sdk 3.0 graph api tut](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook-connect/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

cron knows absolutely NOTHING about Facebook and Facebook credentials, and this is a good thing. If you want a script to do things automatically with Facebook, you'll need to embed your credentials in the script, or give the script access to some place the credentials are stored.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a per user thing, you would need to have a user authenticate with your application, and request offline_access extended permission (in addition to other permissions you might need), and store the resulting access token in some kind of database.  You could then publish as that user using that access token at any time (unless the token gets deactivated by them changing their password or revoking access).

If you just need to do this for your own account, you would do the same process of getting an offline_access token but you could just embed this access token into the code of your application.